# Legality of screenshots from TV commercials

Tags: copyright, academic-writing, graphics

Screenshots from TV commercials.

I'm writing a book on costume design for students and I want to show an image from A TV commercial showing an example of advertising costuming style. Is it legal to take a screenshot from a TV commercial to publish in an academic book as I believe it is to take from a film trailer?

Comment: (1) Please state your jurisdiction (as well as the jurisdition of the copyright material if it is not the same) when you ask legal questions. The law isn't the same everywhere. (2) We are all laypeople here and you will have to ask a qualified lawyer no matter what the answers here say, so you may just as well ask a lawyer right away. (3) What is the purpose of providing that illustration? Do you discuss the advertising (might be fair use), or do you discuss the costume (might not be fair use)?

Comment: (4) How do you intend to publish that book? Non-fiction concepts are usually submitted to publishers before the book is written. Details such as your question can then be discussed with the publisher who has legal experts.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your questions. I am the author and a costume designer writing on my subject. The purpose of including the photograph is to illustrate typical costume design/styling in advertising (I'm discussing the costume) which is different to other genres. I've had permission from the commercial's director, and I've tried the advertising agency who suggested going to Ikea, but I don't know where to start. The book is being published by a large international publisher (UK and US). I hope they can ask their lawyer, but my request hasn't been acknowledged. I am finalising image permissions.

Answer (score 1):

[Fair Use Rule of Copyright](https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/fair-use-rule-copyright-material-30100.html#:%7E:text=Section%20107%20of%20the%20Copyright%20Act%20of%201986,or%20research%2C%20is%20not%20an%20infringement%20of%20copyright.%22)

This sounds like fair use:
Quoting: "Section 107 of the Copyright Act of 1986 (17 U.S. Code § 107) states that fair use of copyrighted material "for purposes such as criticism, comment, news reporting, teaching (including multiple copies for classroom use), scholarship, or research, is not an infringement of copyright."

If you go to that link, you can also find an attorney, with an initial free consultation, to talk  to.

Outside the USA, I am not sure what laws apply; but if you are using a regular publisher, they will vet every image use for copyright violation. Keep track of where you got each image and when; you might want to include that information alongside the text.

EDIT: The OP is in the UK. In the UK, "fair use" is called "fair dealing". I have not read them in detail, but it seems the UK provides exceptions (a good thing) for Research, Education, Criticism and Review.

Here are some links from a google search on fair dealing in the UK.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing_in_United_Kingdom_law

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/exceptions-to-copyright

https://copyrightservice.co.uk/copyright/p09_fair_use

https://www.bl.uk/business-and-ip-centre/articles/fair-dealing-copyright-explained

Comment: Thank you for your advice on this. I am in the UK, and I have asked the publisher this question, but I have not received an answer.

Comment: @Vin I added to my answer for copyright law in the UK. In the UK Fair Use is called Fair Dealing. It appears very similar exceptions apply as in the USA ((that's good for you) , but I did not read these links in detail. Of course, you should look it up for anyplace you intend to sell your book. Or again, rely on your publisher.

Comment: thank you for this information, it's really helpful to know. Vin

Comment: @Vin You can "accept" this answer, if you think it is the best answer to your question.

Comment: I’m not sure how to accept this answer?

Comment: @Vin Me either, I only answer questions! I think there is something under the score on this answer, where you can vote it up or vote it down, it is only available to the asker.

Comment: @Vin Actually, near the score on the question (the up and down arrows), if you are the author of the question there should also be a Checkmark outlined below the up-down arrows. If you click on that, it will fill in. You can click it again or change your selection at any time, if a better 'best answer" shows up.